# How to set fix dates in bootstrap-datepicker?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to set some fix dates in datepicker as follows:

**01/01/2018

01/04/2018

01/07/2018

01/10/2018**

I have tried following

```
var dt = new Date();
var yr = dt.getFullYear();
var dateArr = [(new Date("04-01-" + yr)), (new Date("01-01-" + yr)), (new Date("07-01-" + yr)), (new Date("10-01-" + yr))]
$("#date").datepicker();

for (var j = 0; j < dateArr.length; j++) {
  $("#date").datepicker("setDate", dateArr[j]);
}
```

remain date's  are disabled.
I have tried to  find solution but no result.
Anyone have idea about it.

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**

After applying your function its look likes flollows:

[image]

The date is not disabled as i want

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

This code will definitely help you. They `beforeshowDay` is what you are looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
initComponent();
});

function initComponent()
{
var dt = new Date();
var yr = dt.getFullYear();
dateArr = ['12-05-'+yr,'12-11-'+yr];
$('#date').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        var dmy = (d.getMonth()+1)
        if(d.getMonth()<9) 
            dmy="0"+dmy; 
        dmy+= "-"; 

        if(d.getDate()<10) dmy+="0"; 
            dmy+=d.getDate() + "-" + d.getFullYear(); 
        if ($.inArray(dmy, dateArr) != -1) {
            return [true, "","Available"]; 
        } else{
             return [false,"","unAvailable"]; 
        }
    },
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
    });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
    <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control" name="date" />
    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
```

just pass your dates in `availableDates` array properly and make sure the `dateFormat` matches with your dates in the array.
run the snippet and let me know if this helps you

> Note : as you have updated the question, here I'm providing the complete
>   code from a file that I created on my machine. Just copy it and save
>   it as a html file and see if it's working fine. If it works then probably
>   there's some conflict in your code. Here's the code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-group input-append date" id="dateRangePicker">
    <input type="text" id="date" class="form-control" name="date" />
    <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
initComponent();
});

function initComponent()
{
var dt = new Date();
var yr = dt.getFullYear();
dateArr = ['12-05-'+yr,'12-11-'+yr];
$('#date').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
    beforeShowDay: function(d) {
        var dmy = (d.getMonth()+1)
        if(d.getMonth()<9) 
            dmy="0"+dmy; 
        dmy+= "-"; 

        if(d.getDate()<10) dmy+="0"; 
            dmy+=d.getDate() + "-" + d.getFullYear(); 
        if ($.inArray(dmy, dateArr) != -1) {
            return [true, "","Available"]; 
        } else{
             return [false,"","unAvailable"]; 
        }
    },
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
    });


}
</script>
</html>
```

just save it as html and directly open it in your browser and do let me know if it works. We'll surely fix your issue

Comment: new Date("04-01-" + yr) this will give you an invalid date that's why  the code won't work if you take dates like this

Comment: check my updated answer. I've shown how to do it by your method

Comment: can you post your html code or give a fiddle of your code complete code for the calender page along with the header part of the html so that I can see which js and css you have included or I can set it up on my machine see what's wrong?

Comment: simply give me a jsfiddle or a gist of your code and I'll fix it

Comment: your answer is not working for me, thanks for ur efforts. I have do this things using another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **beforeShowDay** parameter to enable only that dates which you want. you can use below code to achieve your task.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var enableDays = ["1-12-2018","11-12-2018","21-12-2018"];
    function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
        var sdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'd-m-yy', date)
        console.log(sdate)
        if($.inArray(sdate, enableDays) != -1) {
            return [true];
        }
        return [false];
    }
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', beforeShowDay:enableAllTheseDays});
})
```

But if you are using bootstrap date picker you can update **datesDisabled** setting.

below is a sample of **datesDisabled**

```
var datesForDisable = ["2018-12-14","2018-10-1","2017-10-26"]

$('yourselector').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoclose: true,
            weekStart: 1,
            calendarWeeks: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            datesDisabled: datesForDisable,
})
```

Comment: Thanks but not working for me. i am used bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: well both the answer's are also about the same datepicker that you are using

Comment: @pravinnavle can you make a fiddle?